# Data partitioning according two variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, partitioning

I am working with the following dataset:

```
dataFrame <- read.table(header=T, text='Students  Year    Score    Flag
1    0    62    0
1    1    66    0
1    2    62    0
1    3    73    0
2    0    70    0
2    1    50    0
2    2    50    0
2    3    70    0
3    0    68    0
3    1    74    0
3    2    68    0
3    3    78    0
4    0    50    0
4    1    50    0
4    2    50    0
4    3    58    0
5    0    63    0
5    1    63    0
5    2    67    0
5    3    70    0
6    0    63    0
6    1    63    0
6    2    63    0
6    3    69    0
7    0    62    0
7    1    63    0
7    2    64    0
7    3    65    0
8    0    67    0
8    1    73    0
8    2    65    0
8    3    75    0
9    0    54    1
9    1    63    1
9    2    50    1
9    3    49    1
9    3    50    1
10    0    60    1
10    1    81    1
10    2    50    1
10    3    49    1')
```

In the dataset above I have the following variables:

"Students": factor with 10 levels (1,2,...,10)

"Year": factor with 4 levels (0,1,2,3)

The dependent variable "Score"

and a variable "Flag" that idenfies students that had at least 1 "Score" below 50 in the Year 3

In this data set the only two students "Flag" = 1 are the "Student" = 9 and "Student" = 10.

What I would like to achieve is a balanced partition of the data set that takes into account both the variable "Flag" and the variable "Students".
For instance in this data set this means to have the "Student" 9 in one partition and the 10 in the other, for instance:

training

```
Students  Year    Score    Flag
1    0    62    0
1    1    66    0
1    2    62    0
1    3    73    0
2    0    70    0
2    1    50    0
2    2    50    0    
2    3    70    0
3    0    68    0
3    1    74    0
3    2    68    0
3    3    78    0
4    0    50    0
4    1    50    0
4    2    50    0
4    3    58    0
6    0    63    0
6    1    63    0
6    2    63    0
6    3    69    0
10    0    60    1
10    1    81    1
10    2    50    1
10    3    49    1
```

test

```
Students  Year    Score    Flag
5    0    63    0
5    1    63    0
5    2    67    0
5    3    70    0
6    0    63    0
6    1    63    0
6    2    63    0
6    3    69    0
7    0    62    0
7    1    63    0
7    2    64    0
7    3    65    0
8    0    67    0
8    1    73    0
8    2    65    0
8    3    75    0
9    0    54    1
9    1    63    1
9    2    50    1
9    3    49    1
9    3    50    1
```

I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work

```
library(caret)
trainIndex                  <- createDataPartition( c( dataFrame$Flag , dataFrame$Students ) , 
                                                p     = .6 ,
                                                list  = FALSE ,
                                                times = 1 )


dataFrame[ trainIndex , ]
dataFrame[ -trainIndex , ]
```

What would be the best way of obtaning what I need?

Many thanks

Comment: c( dataFrame\$Flag , dataFrame\$Students ) concatenated the two vectors (giving you one of twice the length); what you want is a "rowwise" concatenation.  Add a column to your dataframe with something like within(dataFrame, newcol <- paste(as.character(Flag), as.character(Students))).

Comment: @kasterma thanks for your reply. I don't think your solution is producing what I need: the students 9 and 10 end up in both train and test data sets

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood.  I still do (since I don't understand the flag variable and its properties), but the student 9 and 10 problem can be solved by using createDataPartition on the levels of the student variable (as you read it in above Students is not a factor, but you can make it so). trainIdx <- createDataPartition(levels(dataFrame\$Students), .....)  Then trainstudentIds = levels(dataFrame\$Students)[trainIdx].

Comment: @kasterma thanks again, maybe, if I explain the background it would be a bit more clear what I am trying to achive here.

Comment: In the original data set I have a large cohort of students and I want to predict who is going to fail ("Score" < 50) in the third year ("Year" = 3) by looking at previous performance ("Year" = 0,1,2) and other predictors. 
The proportion of such failing students is very low and If I randomly partition I might end up having no failing students in train or test.Therefore I need to make sure I pick up a balanced ammount of failures ("Flag"=1) and successes ("Flag"=0) but also I need to insure that the same Student is not scattered in different data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth in comments I think I understand

First get a table of students and flags, in this case obtained by

```
flaggedStudents <- dataFrame[!duplicated(dataFrame$Students),c(1,4)]
```

Then from the students pick a balanced partition using createDataPartition

```
trainStudents <- createDataPartition(flaggedStudents$Flag, p=0.6, list=FALSE, times=1)
```

Then you have the training frame as follows:

```
dataFrame[dataFrame$Student %in% trainStudents,]
```

and testing frame:

```
dataFrame[!dataFrame$Student %in% trainStudents,]
```

Better would be to "normalize" your whole dataframe.  Now you have a flag variable that is per student, repeated in multiple rows, but these rows have a varying score depending on the second column.  I wrote that nice and messy, because it is.

An interesting paper describing how you might like your data to be is [tidy data by Hadley Wickham (pdf)](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: interesting: your solution seems to be working only if "Students" and "Flag" are forced to factors: if I set.seed( 1 ) and run createDataPartition with the variables as NOT factors I obtain the following students: 2,3,4,5,7,8 (so the flagged students 9 &  10 are kept together). Any idea why? Also, I can't keep the data in the large format (if that was what your where thinking) because some students had to take Year 3 multiple times

Comment: @user44252 "so the flagged students 9 & 10 are kept together" this will happen with probability 0.6 * 0.6 + 0.4 * 0.4 (either both in train class, or both in test class).

Comment: but then why when "Students" and "Flag" are turned into factors your solution works fine?
Anyway, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of sharing a working example, here is the solution based on the suggestion made above by @kasterma.

The relevant variables must be turned into factors in order to have the code working properly.

```
dataFrame$Students <- factor( dataFrame$Students )
dataFrame$Flag     <- factor( dataFrame$Flag )

flaggedStudents <- dataFrame[!duplicated(dataFrame$Students),c(1,4)]

trainStudents <- createDataPartition(flaggedStudents$Flag, p=0.6, list=FALSE, times=1)

dataFrame[ dataFrame$Student %in% trainStudents , ]
   dataFrame[!dataFrame$Student %in% trainStudents , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great! But it does not work when the "Student" (id) values are characters. It can be made to, by adding one line:

```
trainStudents <-  unique(dataFrame$Students)[trainStudents]
```

just before running

```
dataFrame[ dataFrame$Student %in% trainStudents , ]
```

This updates the numeric identifiers returned by `createDataPartition`  into the actual values of the IDs.